# Is it possible to save form data without user submitting form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, email

I am trying to create a signup/login form. I want to have a single form field. As the user types their email address into the field, the email address is checked against the user database. If the email is found in the user database a password field is displayed, and the user logs in after entering their password.

If the email was not found in the user database, a create account form displays. The email that was entered is then saved to the autoresponder (mail chimp) automatically weather the user continues to create their account at that moment or not.

How could I go about doing this using JS/jQuery?

As a starting point I was thinking that I can do something like this:

```
<input onchange="checkDatabase();" onkeyup="this.checkDatabase();" onpaste="this.checkDatabase();" oninput="this.checkDatabase();">
```

However the event fires on every keypress, which will give false positives until the entire email address is entered. How could I write that code so that it only fires after it detects '.com' (plus any other TLD names I add)

Comment: You can create a `ajax` request on `focusout` email field and then get email existing information and according to result show password field or create account fields

Comment: You can also use blur event to make a ajax call to validate email address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ajax to do the thing.

```
function load(id,url,type,data,json,callback) {
    var xmlhttp;

    (window.XMLHttpRequest)?xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest():xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {  
            ((id != "")?(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText):(((json == true)?(callback(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText))):(callback(xmlhttp.responseText)))));
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open(type,url,true);

    if(type == "POST") {
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(data);
    } else {
        xmlhttp.send();
    }   

}
```

then just call it when the user types in the field

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('email-field').addEventListener('keyup',function() {
       load("","php/check_password.php","POST","email="+document.getElementById('email-field').value+"",false,function(data) {
              if (data === true) {
                 document.getElementById('password-field').style.display = "block";
                 document.getElementById('create-account-form').style.display = "none";
              } else {
                 document.getElementById('create-account-form').style.display = "block";
                 document.getElementById('password-field').style.display = "none";
              }
       });
    });
};
```

db_config.php:

```
<?php

    DEFINE("HOST","localhost");                         // Host Name
    DEFINE("USER","root");                              // Database Username
    DEFINE("PASSWORD","");                              // Database Password
    DEFINE("DATABASE","db_osgamdrp");                   // Database Name
    DEFINE("TIMEZONE","Asia/Manila");                   // Server Timezone

?>
```

db_connect.php:

```
<?php

    include_once "db_config.php";

    date_default_timezone_set(TIMEZONE);

    class Connection {
        function con() {

            $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);

            if (!$con) {
                die("Error :" . mysqli_error());
            }

            return $con;
        }
    }

?>
```

check_password.php

```
<?php

    /* Database Connection */
    include_once "db_connect.php";

    $Connection = new connection();

    $Query = mysqli_query($Connection->con(),"SELECT 
                                              Email
                                              FROM TABLE
                                              WHERE Email = '" . htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) . "'");

    if ($Row = mysqli_fetch_array($Query)) {
        echo true;
    else {
        echo false;
    }

    mysqli_close($Connection->con());                                     
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) or AJAX.

> XMLHttpRequest (XHR) is an API available to web browser scripting languages such as JavaScript. It is used to send HTTP or HTTPS requests to a web server and load the server response data back into the script.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) Development versions of all major browsers support URI schemes beyond http and https, in particular, blob URLs are supported

jQuery has form validation plugins you could use and find after a quick Google search.

Alternatively, you could try something like in [this](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/jscript/article.php/c19617/Client-Side-Validation-Using-the-XMLHTTPRequest-Object.htm) example. I modified it to work for all major browsers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateEmail(semail) {
document.body.style.cursor='wait';
// Create an instance of the XML HTTP Request object

var oXMLHTTP;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  oXMLHTTP=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  oXMLHTTP=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

// Prepare the XMLHTTP object for a HTTP POST to our validation ASP page
var sURL = "http://mysite/mypath/validateemail.asp?email=" + semail
oXMLHTTP.open( "POST", sURL, false );
// Execute the request
oXMLHTTP.send();
if (oXMLHTTP.responseText == "exists") 
alert("Sorry - the Email " + semail + " already exists.");
document.body.style.cursor='auto';
}
</script>
```

Then just have your serverside script respond with "exists" if the email exists.